# 'FontAwesomeIcon' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

When I tried to **add font awesome to react**, I'm getting the error like it is not defined.

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-xmark" /> //from font awesome

"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1" this is the library which I've installed on modules.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've used fontawesome react component for adding icons but when I used <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-xmark" /> it's showing it's not defined. I've added the library to the file but still it's showing like this

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
```

and then

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark}/>
```

Comment: You're saying that he should use pro icons, but you forget to specify that it won't work without the appropriate configuration (as pro icons need money)

Comment: then he can import it like
`import { faXmark } from  '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'`

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong dependency, as [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react) explains it:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

> NOTE : `npm i` and `npm install` do the exact same thing.

To install the different types of icons, use this,

- for solid icons:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

- regular icons:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

etc.

More on their [official documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react).